# R Shiny: Table object not found in reactive RMySQL query in shiny app

Tags: mysql, r, shiny

***[EDIT]: solution by agstudy worked for me.***

I have a shiny app that allows users to toggle between three tables in a MySQL database. Users can select a table which is used by renderTable to generate the object.

I have put if statements in renderTable to respond to the users' selected table.

When I run the app, any table fails to print and cannot be viewed.

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(RMySQL)

con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),user="x",password="x",host="dbhost",dbname="db")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  data <- reactive({ 
    selectInput("input$data", "Choose your Input:", choices = c('data1'='1','data2'='2', 'data3'='3'))
  })

    output$table <- renderTable({
      if(input$data == data1){
        query1 <- reactive({ "SELECT *
                            FROM data1
                            ORDER BY var1, var2"})
        reactive({dbGetQuery(con,query1())})
        head(data())

      } else if(input$data == data2){
        query1 <- reactive({ "SELECT *
                            FROM data2
                            ORDER BY var1, var2"})
        reactive({dbGetQuery(con,query1())})
        head(data())

      } else if(input$data == data3){
        query1 <- reactive({ "SELECT *
                            FROM data3
                            ORDER BY var1, var2"})
        reactive({dbGetQuery(con,query1())})
        head(data())

      } else print("Select a dataset")

    })

})
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library('RMySQL')

shinyUI(navbarPage("Test",


                   tabPanel("Test",
                            sidebarLayout(
                              sidebarPanel(
                                selectInput("data", label = "Data set",
                                            choices = c("", "data1", "data2", "data3"))

                                ),

                              mainPanel(
                                tableOutput("table")



                              )
                            ))
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is not in any case related to MySQLserver but there is a no UI logic.  Programming in `Shiny` is not easy if you don't isolate your code parts:

- inputs: defined in your ui interface
- reactive functions : should change each time you change your input
- outputs: be refreshed once the input data is changed by the reactive function.

You miss-understand the `reactive`.The basic idea is that your don't need to refresh your UI  manually, it should be done automatically once the input parameter is changed.

Here I am rewriting completely your code using the Shiny logic:

```
library(RMySQL)
library(shiny)
## this a public function that will be used
## in the server side to connect to the data base
## and retrieve data
get_data <- 
  function(query){
    on.exit(dbDisconnect(conn)) ## important to close connection
    conn <- dbConnect("MySQL",user="xuser",
                      password="xpws",
                      host="xhost",
                      dbname="xdbname")
    dbGetQuery(con,query)
  }

server <- shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {
    ## the reactive engine that will refresh query 
    ## each time input changed 
    query <- reactive( sprintf("SELECT * 
                    FROM %s 
                    ORDER BY var1, var2",input$data)

    )
    ## simply  displaying reactive inputs
    output$table <- renderTable(
      if(input$data!="") get_data(query())
    )
  })

## define ui elements by step
## for easy indenting
ui_panel <- 
  tabPanel("Test",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               selectInput("data", label = "Data set",
                           choices = c("","data1", "data2", "data3"))
             ),
             mainPanel(
               tableOutput("table")
             )
           )
  )


ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage("Test",ui_panel))

runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server))
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. This solution worked for me.